# multiple users edit website over ssh

Tags: ssh, web

I have setup a server with my account as the owner of the html files.  I edit the files with vim over ssh.  I want to allow DevB and DevC to also edit the files over ssh.  As I understand linux permissions that means I would need to set the group that owns the files to one that we all use and allow that group write permissions.  Is that the best way to go about it or is that a really bad way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking along the same lines i was when i set up my webserver:

Each project (website, source tree) has a useraccount (for automated shell scripts and whatnot), as well as a usergroup. Then all the devs that should be allowed to edit the project gets added to that same usergroup. Then just make sure that the group flag is 6 or 7.

While that's an approach that i like, it has its limitations: When one coder screws up, he does so for everybody else. You might want to look into subversioning, in the form of git, SVN, CVS, or any of the others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But apache (or whatever web server) would need to be a member of that group too right?  Would that mean that every file/directory was writable by the web server?

Comment: Not really. If you use a permission such as 664, and leave apache alone in its own group, it'll use the everyone-else-flag, which in a 664 mask is only read access.